# I am getting java.lang.ArithmeticException error

Tags: java, math

This is inside the main method. Trying to compute the double x math formula and it is giving me problem running the code. Can someone please help?

```
final int P = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
final int Q = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
final double H = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
final int N = Spiro.numberOfRevolutions(P, Q);

IPoint2D point = new IPoint2D(0., 0.);
SimpleDrawing.drawPoint(point);

for (int i = 1; i <= 360*N; i++) {
    final int r = P/Q;
    double radianI = Math.toRadians(i);
    double x = ((1 - r) * Math.cos(radianI)) + (H * Math.cos(((1- r) / r) *  radianI));
    double y = ((1 - r) * Math.sin(radianI)) + (H * Math.sin(((1- r) / r) * radianI));

    IPoint2D point1 = new IPoint2D(x,y);
    SimpleDrawing.drawPoint(point1);
}
```

Comment: Is there a `0` somewhere?

Comment: Can you put in the exact exception you have got?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: It means you have provided something that your calculator would represent as "Math error", usually when the result is infinite or not a number (non existent), or divide by zero is the most common.

Answer (score 4):

If `P` is smaller than `Q` (or `Q` is `0` will immediately throw the `ArithmeticException`)

```
final int r = P/Q;
```

`r` will have a value of `0`. You then divide by `r=0`

```
double x = ((1 - r) * Math.cos(radianI)) + (H * Math.cos(((1- r) / r) *  radianI));
```

throwing the `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this :

```
final int r = P/Q;
```

You need to make sure Q is never zero, otherwise it would be ArithmeticException